# hibernate joins not working

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I am new in hibernate.i have 2 two tables one is job and other is jobSkills. but when i insert data into database using jsp form.all data is going properly but jobID is going null
i know its simple but i don't know how to solve it.
please help me

code in job class :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="job",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List <JobSkill> jobSkill;

 public List<JobSkill> getJobSkill() {
 return jobwalkintime;
 }


  public void setJobSkill(List<JobSkill> jobSkill) {
   this.jobSkill = jobSkill;
   }
```

code in JobSkill class :

```
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "JobId")
  private Job job;
```

Comment: What annotation you apply for jobId?

Comment: one thing i want to share u jobId is generated automatic in job table.and its working fine.but jobid is null in jobskill table. and i am using annotion on jobid  @Id

Comment: Please show the java code where you setting the bean values to save.

Answer (score 0):

I would really guess problem is with your `Set Accessor` method i..e set methods in both JobSkill and Job. Change your `setJobSkill` method as below

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="job",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List <JobSkill> jobSkill = new ArrayList<JobSkill>();

public List<JobSkill> getJobSkill() {
 return jobwalkintime;
}
public void setJobSkill(List<JobSkill> jobSkill) {
 if (jobSkill != null ) {
   for (JobSkill js : jobSkill) {
   js.setJob(this);
 }
 this.jobSkill = jobSkill;
}
```

In JPA world `JobSkill` will be owner of relation, so you set `Job` instance on each `JobSkill` to establish relation b/w them.

In General , for Bi-directional one-to-many two way relation , `Accessor` method should like below and assume entities are `Customer` and `Order` and one-to-many relation b/w them.

**Customer.java**

```
public Collection<Order> getOrders() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(orders);
}

public void addToOrders(Order value) {
    if (!orders.contains(value)) {
        orders.add(value);
        value.setCustomer(this);
    }
}

public void removeFromOrders(Order value) {
    if (orders.remove(value)) {
        value.setCustomer(null);
    }
}
```

**Order.java**

```
public void setCustomer(Customer value) {
    if (this.customer != value) {
        if (this.customer != null) {
            this.customer.removeFromOrders(this);
        }
        this.customer = value;
        if (value != null) {
            value.addToOrders(this);
        }
    }
}

public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}
```

Comment: i did same as u told me and i change my jobskill setter method .but again jobId is null in table jobskill

Comment: Can you update your question with latest code :), so that we can a look. If possible try to put code how you persist